# ScalaTest in sbt: is there a way to run a single test without tags?

Tags: scala, testing, sbt, scalatest

I know that a single test can be ran by running, in sbt,

```
testOnly *class -- -n Tag
```

Is there a way of telling sbt/scalatest to run a single test without tags? For example:

```
testOnly *class -- -X 2
```

it would mean "run the second test in the class. Whatever it is". We have a bunch of tests and no one bothered to tag them, so is there a way to run a single test without it having a tag?

Comment: Your subject says "Scalatest-sbt". When sbt is hyphenated people would normally think of a plugin. But, just to clarify, you're talking about using [ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.org/) from a modern version of sbt like sbt 0.12, not [joshcough/scalatest-sbt](https://github.com/joshcough/scalatest-sbt) a plugin for sbt 0.5.2-p3 written 4 years ago. Correct?

Comment: Correct. This is an old question and I have since then figured out that no, it is not possible (as far as I know). I haven't closed it in case someone did in fact managed to figure out a way, but I no longer need this to be answered.

Comment: There is a thread on this (with participation from both Bill Venners and Mark Harrah) at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scalatest-users/1oRMkudFAXM , but no solution yet

Comment: There's also a case for general support on running a single test sbt#911 (https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/911).

Comment: Note that if you're running from the command line, [you have to enclose everything after `sbt` in quotes](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/issues/357), e.g. `sbt "test-only *SingleTestSuite"`

Comment: the quotes are shell syntax, preventing sbt from interpreting the single command as a series of commands, while also preventing the shell from expanding `*`. `MySuite` is a class name

Answer (score 269, accepted):

This is now supported (since ScalaTest 2.1.3) within interactive mode:

```
testOnly *MySuite -- -z foo
```

to run only the tests whose name includes the substring "foo".

For exact match rather than substring, use `-t` instead of `-z`.

---

If you run it from the command line, it should be as single argument to sbt:

```
sbt 'testOnly *MySuite -- -z foo'
```

Comment: @SethTisue Would you be able to post a working example which uses `-t` for exact matching? I am unable to get it to work.

Comment: @rmin https://gist.github.com/SethTisue/f75cd8b72128ba0a0a81. (if this helps you fix your problem, let me know how I should update my answer.)

Comment: @SethTisue Thanks for the link. I tried this and it doesn't work on my particular project even though `-z` does. Not a big deal. Mine is a play app using `org.scalatestplus` version 1.1.0 so maybe it's related to that.

Comment: For JUnitSuite in Scala, it doesn't work. Do you know what kind of options should I use?

Comment: In case anyone wants to run a specific integration test (supposedly placed under `src/it`), they need to prepend `it` to `testOnly`. For instance, on the command line: `sbt "it:testOnly *MyIntegrationTestSuite"`.

Comment: How can I filter on multiple substrings?
Tests may be grouped in a hierarchy (WordSpec), and the name parts separated by `when` and `should`  can repeat between tests. To chose one specific test I need to say "name contains this AND that".

Comment: can you further explain this syntax? what is the quote near testOnly? What is MySuite? should that be the name of the project?

Comment: the single quotes have two purposes: to tell sbt that the whole thing is a single command and not a series of them, and to prevent the shell from interpreting the `*` as a glob. `MySuite` is the name of a test class

Answer (score 147):

*I wanted to add a concrete example to accompany the other answers*

You need to specify the name of the class that you want to test, so if you have the following project (this is a Play project):

[image: Play Project]

You can test just the `Login` tests by running the following command from the SBT console:

```
test:testOnly *LoginServiceSpec
```

If you are running the command from outside the SBT console, you would do the following:

```
sbt "test:testOnly *LoginServiceSpec"
```

Comment: Upvote because apparently the double quotes are necessary: ```sbt "test:testOnly *LoginServiceSpec"```

Comment: Most useful answer for me here.  But the commands can be slightly simplified; in SBT console: `testOnly *LoginServiceSpec`, and outside: `sbt "testOnly *LoginServiceSpec"`

Comment: It seems that this is a sbt 0.13 syntax. Either use `sbt "Test/testOnly *LoginServiceSpec` or event better as mentioned elsewhere `sbt "testOnly *LoginServiceSpec"`

Answer (score 57):

I don't see a way to run a single untagged test within a test class but I am providing my workflow since it seems to be useful for anyone who runs into this question.

From within a sbt session:

```
test:testOnly *YourTestClass
```

(The asterisk is a wildcard, you could specify the full path `com.example.specs.YourTestClass`.)

All tests within that test class will be executed. Presumably you're most concerned with failing tests, so correct any failing implementations and then run:

```
test:testQuick
```

... which will only execute tests that failed. (Repeating the most recently executed `test:testOnly` command will be the same as `test:testQuick` in this case, but if you break up your test methods into appropriate test classes you can use a wildcard to make `test:testQuick` a more efficient way to re-run failing tests.)

Note that the nomenclature for test in ScalaTest is a test class, not a specific test method, so all untagged methods are executed.

If you have too many test methods in a test class break them up into separate classes or tag them appropriately. (This could be a signal that the class under test is in violation of [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and could use a refactoring.)

Comment: for who are facing "No tests were executed": `*YourTestClass` must be class name. Not file name.

Comment: it was testOnly instead of test-only for me.

Comment: Like the explanation of what the * meant.

Answer (score 25):

Just to simplify the example of Tyler.

**`test:`-prefix is not needed.**

So according to his example:

In the `sbt`-console:

```
testOnly *LoginServiceSpec
```

And in the terminal:

```
sbt "testOnly *LoginServiceSpec"
```

Answer (score 19):

Here's the Scalatest page on [using the runner](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_runner) and [the extended discussion on the `-t` and `-z` options](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_runner#selectingSuitesAndTests).

This post shows what commands work for a test file that uses `FunSpec`.

Here's the test file:

```
package com.github.mrpowers.scalatest.example

import org.scalatest.FunSpec

class CardiBSpec extends FunSpec {

  describe("realName") {

    it("returns her birth name") {
      assert(CardiB.realName() === "Belcalis Almanzar")
    }

  }

  describe("iLike") {

    it("works with a single argument") {
      assert(CardiB.iLike("dollars") === "I like dollars")
    }

    it("works with multiple arguments") {
      assert(CardiB.iLike("dollars", "diamonds") === "I like dollars, diamonds")
    }

    it("throws an error if an integer argument is supplied") {
      assertThrows[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException]{
        CardiB.iLike()
      }
    }

    it("does not compile with integer arguments") {
      assertDoesNotCompile("""CardiB.iLike(1, 2, 3)""")
    }

  }

}
```

This command runs the four tests in the `iLike` describe block (from the SBT command line):

```
testOnly *CardiBSpec -- -z iLike
```

You can also use quotation marks, so this will also work:

```
testOnly *CardiBSpec -- -z "iLike"
```

This will run a single test:

```
testOnly *CardiBSpec -- -z "works with multiple arguments"
```

This will run the two tests that start with "works with":

```
testOnly *CardiBSpec -- -z "works with"
```

I can't get the `-t` option to run any tests in the `CardiBSpec` file.  This command doesn't run any tests:

```
testOnly *CardiBSpec -- -t "works with multiple arguments"
```

Looks like the `-t` option works when tests aren't nested in `describe` blocks.  Let's take a look at another test file:

```
class CalculatorSpec extends FunSpec {
  it("adds two numbers") {
    assert(Calculator.addNumbers(3, 4) === 7)
  }
}
```

`-t` can be used to run the single test:

```
testOnly *CalculatorSpec -- -t "adds two numbers"
```

`-z` can also be used to run the single test:

```
testOnly *CalculatorSpec -- -z "adds two numbers"
```

See [this repo](https://github.com/MrPowers/scalatest-example) if you'd like to run these examples.  You can find more info on running tests [here](https://mungingdata.com/scala/scalatest/).

Comment: Wow man! This is really an innovative test suite I have encountered in my life. Hats off.