# Run just a specific scalatest test from sbt

Tags: sbt, scalatest

`sbt`'s `test-only` command can be used to run the tests found in a specific test class. With JUnit tests you can use `test-only` to run specific methods on a test class e.g. `test-only mypackage.MyTestClass.test1Equals1` to run just that method.

Is such a thing possible with scalatest's more free-form test syntax, presumably by working out the name it uses internally to reference a specific test? If it isn't possible in `FreeSpec` (which is easy to imagine given its nature) is there a way to do it with a simpler testing approach like `FunSuite`?

Comment: There's a feature open for this on sbt.   Part of this involves how we fingerprint tests to run and the framework integration.  It was scheduled for 0.13.2, but was just too hairy to finish. I'm hoping we'll have time for it in 0.13.3.

Comment: Thanks @jsuereth. When it makes it into a release put an answer down here if you remember :-)

Comment: @jsuereth, is [this](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/911) the enhancement that you are referring to?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For a general solution we need to wait for [sbt#911](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/911), but apparently [ScalaTest 2.1.3](http://www.scalatest.org/release_notes/2.1.3) has a support for running a specific test. [Seth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22490924/3827) says:

> This is now supported in ScalaTest 2.1.3 with:

```
test-only *MySuite -- -z foo
```

> to run only the tests whose name includes the substring "foo". For exact match rather than substring, use `-t` instead of `-z`.

Comment: Worth noting that generally, `sbt`'s `test-only` passes arguments to the underlying test runner and `scalatest` now supports `-z "<string to match>"`. Other test frameworks will take different arguments.

Comment: Using ScalaTest 3.0.5 this seems to have changed to `testOnly` instead of `test-only`.

Comment: I also needed quotes in bash, so `sbt "testOnly com.path.to.UnitTestSpec -- -z foo"`

Answer (score 2):

To run a test:

> sbt test-only com.path.to.UnitTestSpec

To run a particular integration test:

> sbt it:test-only com.path.to.IntegrationTestSpec

Comment: Although this answer does not answer OPs question, it's relevant and shows in the search results. To run from terminal, it's `sbt "testOnly com.path.to.UnitTestSpec"`. Quotes make sure that the argument is passed on.