# activator (Play) testOnly runs all tests; how to run really only some of them?

Tags: unit-testing, playframework

I'm using Play framework 2.3.

When I run `activator testOnly controller.MyTestClassName.*` it runs all tests (including MyTestClassName),  exactly like `activator test` does.

I need to run only some of my tests. How it can be done?

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible in Play. I'd like this too.

Answer (score 16):

This is how it has to be done:

```
activator "test-only controller.MyTestClassName"
```

With the quotes!

Comment: Exactly, without double quotes it just ignores everything after `test-only`.

Answer (score 0):

the parameter is `test-only` and not `testOnly`.
Try this:

```
activator test-only controller.MyTestClassName
```

Edit: For further information check out the documentation: [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaTest)

Comment: Anyway, it behaves exactly like "test".

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43103983

sbt "test:test-only controller.MyTestClassName.*"

activator "test:test-only controller.MyTestClassName.*"