# sbt test-only specific test

Tags: scala, sbt

I have several tests distributed over several classes.

I would like to run only the first test from the first class:

The class is:

```
class Step1_PrimarySpec
```

The test is:

```
  test("case1: Primary (in isolation) should properly register itself to the provided Arbiter")
```

I tried:

```
sbt test-only Step1_PrimarySpec
```

and:

```
sbt test-only Step1_PrimarySpec 1
```

and:

```
 sbt test-only "*Step1_PrimarySpec 1"
```

and:

```
 sbt test-only "*Step1_PrimarySpec"
```

However, all of these commands ran the entire test suite.

So how can I run only that specific test?

Answer (score 6):

You must place the double quotes around the whole command like this:

```
sbt "test-only <test-name>"
```

And according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22490924) answer you should camelCase it to `testOnly` and use the `-z` argument

Comment: sbt "test-only org.path.to.test.testClassName"

Comment: I don't think test-only is a valid sbt command, at least in 2023

Answer (score 3):

```
sbt "testOnly *Step1_PrimarySpec -- -z mytest"
```

That will run the test named *mytest* from the *class* (not the *file*) named `Step1_PrimarySpec`.

By using the `*`, the test runner saves us from specifying its fully qualified class name. i.e. *org.path.to.Step1_PrimarySpec*

Comment: Note that this is specific to ScalaTest.

Comment: what is the role of "mytest" here?

Comment: Please re-read the answer. `mytest` is the name of your test.