# How to run single test from test class scala?

Tags: scala, maven

I have such class with tests:

```
class TestSuite {

  @Test def one(): Unit = {
    println(1)
  }

  @Test def two(): Unit = {
    println(2)
  }

  @Test def three(): Unit = {
    println(3)
  }
}
```

I would like to run only for example test with name `three` and don't run another ones. I have maven project with 2.13.6 scala version so I tried to run single test via this command:

```
 mvn test -Dtest="TestSuite@two"
```

but I got the error which is posted below:

```
 No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.)
```

I saw this command on the official maven docs so I thought that it will work well, but it didn't. So, maybe I did smth wrong and we have another command for running one test from testing class and ignoring another ones?

Comment: Should be a hash symbol, i.e. `mvn test -Dtest="TestSuite#two"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and we have another command for running one test from testing class and ignoring another ones?

That should be possible, but using [ScalaTest with maven](https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_scalatest_maven_plugin), or [ScalaTest with sbt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159953/scalatest-in-sbt-is-there-a-way-to-run-a-single-test-without-tags).

Comment: yes, I have also scalatest with maven availability, but can you please if it possible add some command sample for running single test?

Comment: @Andrew I only seen it with sbt only, not maven (when using ScalaTest).